# Jumping to specific page with jq.carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm using jq.carousel plugin for a slider and need to be able to pump to a specific page. Here is the plugin: https://github.com/5509/jq.carousel

In the [usage docs](http://5509.github.com/jq.carousel/#usage) there are next & previous functions for navigating the slider pages but I can't see one to call a specific page.

Any ideas? I might have to modify the plugin but want to check that I've not missed some built-in functionality before I tackle it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my idea is to use the start property:

```
var $carousel = $('#carousel_2').carousel({
   start: <ThePageThatYouWant>, 
   indicator: true 
});
```

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NEkpA/

Comment: That's a great idea! It looks like that way doesn't make the carousel slide to the selected frame, just makes it switch, so I'll wait and see if anyone else has other ideas. Just for the Googlers, here's an updated fiddle with added prev/next functions: `http://jsfiddle.net/NEkpA/2/`

Comment: If you can't find a solution greater then this, please, can you give me the best answer? :) Thank you so much and i f you have any kind of problem feel free to contact me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$("#carouselName").carousel().onMoveIndex(_index);
```